# How can you aggregate a checkbox field with SOQL?

Tags: soql, aggregate, inputcheckboxes

I need to get the average completion of a task which is recorded using a checkbox field.  Since that is stored as TRUE and FALSE instead of 1 and 0 it's proving a bit difficult.

I would have liked to do something like this to get the average that the checkbox was checked per person:

```
SELECT OwnerId, AVG(MyCheckbox__c) FROM Object GROUP BY ROLLUP(OwnerId) ORDER BY AVG(MyCheckbox__c)
```

This obviously doesn't work because checkbox fields don't support aggregates.

Are there any options that don't involve making a duplicate field to store the same value in numeric format? I have a hard time believing this isn't a more common issue or that there isn't an approach that I'm just missing.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to calculate the average manually. You'll want to group the data like this:

```
SELECT Count(ID), OwnerId, MyCheckbox__c FROM Object__c GROUP BY OwnerID, MyCheckbox__c
```

You could map the averages like this:

```
class Average {
    Integer yes = 0, no = 0;
    Decimal avg { get { return no == 0? 0: yes/no } }
}

void calcAvg(Set<Id> userIds) {
     Map<Id, Average> averages = new Map<Id, Average>();
     for(Id userId: userIds) {
         averages.put(userId, new Average());
     }
     for(AggregateResult result:[SELECT ... ]) {
         if(result.get('expr2').equals(true)) {
             averages.get((Id)result.get('expr1')).yes = (Decimal)result.get('expr0');
         } else {
             averages.get((Id)result.get('expr1')).no = (Decimal)result.get('expr0');
         }
     }
```

At this point, you'll have your averages expressed as a standard decimal value in your map.

Comment: I realize there are options outside of SOQL, I'm trying to find a solution that can be entirely contained within a single SOQL statement.

Comment: @RyanElkins The only other "solution" is to write a formula field: IF(MyCheckbox__c, 1, 0), then apply an aggregate to that. Unfortunately, SOQL is *not* SQL, and you will find that things that would be trivial in SQL are impossible in SOQL. It's not meant to be as powerful as SQL.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that was probably the case, just thought I'd check to see if there was a better way to handle that.

Comment: @sfdxfox I don't understand why you can't aggregate a checkbox field ? Group by true or false ? That seems simple. Can you please explain

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this by creating a [Formula Field](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_formulas.htm&language=en) to translate the **Checkbox** field into a **Number** field, then the SOQL worked as expected.

[image]

For the following records...

[image]

I got these results...

[image]