# How can I aggregate a Boolean value for a column in SOQL?

Tags: soql, aggregate

I have a custom object `customobj__c` with the following fields:

```
contact__c  (lookup),
responded__c  (boolean),
click_count__c (integer)
...
```

I can aggregate the click_count using:

```
SELECT contact__c, sum(click_count__c )
FROM customobj__c
GROUP BY contact__c
```

But I cannot aggregate `responded__c` as it is a Boolean.

Can anyone suggest a way of returning the number of rows for each `contact__c` where `responded__c` is true?

Comment: Why can't you aggregate on a boolean field ??

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
SELECT contact__c, responded__c, count(id)
FROM customobj__c
GROUP BY contact__c, responded__c
```

This would give up to two rows per contact, one row with true count and one with false count.

Comment: That's excellent. Also I can safely add WHERE responded__c = true and get only one result per contact.

Comment: Yes, although if you add the where requirement and there are no "true" rows for that contact then you will get no rows for the contact. Just something to watch out for if you are intending to use the results of this query to give you a list of all contacts.

Comment: This has been covered in another question, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/59794/how-can-you-aggregate-a-checkbox-field-with-soql

Answer (score -1):

SUM() can't handle booleans, but the boolean can be cast to an int.  You could use SUM(CAST(responded__c AS INT)), or rely on an implicit cast with the more compact SUM(responded__c + 0).

Comment: This may be true in SQL but does not work in SOQL